# How do I delete last local commit in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I accidentally committed the wrong files to Git, but I haven't pushed the commit to the server yet.

How can I delete that commit from the local repository?

Comment: i want to delete only last commit.not all mn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try git-reset https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset you can reset your state to a previous commit keeping your changes. Something like this should work `git reset --soft origin/master`